# QueryDsl fetch lazy property

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, querydsl

I have a property which is usually fetched lazily:

```
@Entity
class Version(...,
              @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
              @Type(type = "text")
              var mappings: String? = null) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private val id = 0
}
```

But sometimes I need to fetch it eagerly. How can I do this with QueryDsl?
This is what I currently have:

```
JPAQuery<Any>(entityManager).from(QVersion.version)
        .where(...)
        .select(QVersion.version)
        .fetchOne()
```

But this results in a Exception when I try to access the property later:

> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: Unable to perform requested lazy initialization [Version.mappings] - no session and settings disallow loading outside the Session

Comment: I believe you have configured bytecode enhancement to be able to lazy load a plain field (not an entity relation). I might be totally wrong; but the whole point of having this is to ensure the field is lazy loaded. If you need to load it eager sometimes; I would recommend extracting the field to a separate entity (with the same table & id  of `Version` of course) i.e. `VersionMappings` and use entity relation instead of field.  So you can do sth like `from(QVersion.version).innerJoin(QVersion.version.mappings).fetchJoin().select(QVersion.version)` to eagerly load the lazy entity relation.

Comment: @feanor07 yes, bytecode enhancement is on. This sounds like a good solution. Could you turn it into an answer with examples of the two entities? I've added a simple id to my version class in the question.

Comment: I will add a working example for you after couple of hours; but it will be in Java not kotlin; I hope this is fine :D

Comment: sure, I can translate to kotlin myself. I've tried what you said but didn't get it to work, so looking forward to the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple solution for this: `.fetchAll()`

```
JPAQuery<Any>(entityManager).from(QVersion.version)
        .fetchAll()  // <- here
        .where(...)
        .select(QVersion.version)
        .fetchOne()
```

Related [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-joins):

> If you are using property-level lazy fetching (with bytecode instrumentation), it is possible to force Hibernate to fetch the lazy properties in the first query immediately using fetch all properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest splitting the table into two separate entities and defining a `lazy OneToOne` relationship and so that you can fetch it eagerly via `QueryDSL` when required. So for your example you might have following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="version")
class Version{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private val id = 0;
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private VersionMappings mappings;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="version")
VersionMappings{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private val id = 0;
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Type(type = "text")
    var mappings: String? = null);
}
```

sorry if the syntax is wrong; since I am not familiar with `Kotlin`. Then you can have eager fetching as follows:

```
    QVersion version = QVersion.version;

    Version versionWithEagerlyFetchedMapping = JPAQuery<>(entityManager).from(version).where(version.id.eq(id)).rightJoin(version.versionMapping).fetchJoin().select(version).fetchOne();
```

I prepared following [github repo](https://github.com/feanor07/table-split-to-two-entities) to demonstrate my suggestion in action. The repo is a Spring Boot Application with 3 separate endpoints:

1. `/books-without-author/{id}` ==> Gets the book without author
2. `/books-with-author-exception/{id}` ==> Tries to get the book with author but throws exception due to transaction not available to load the proxy
3. `/books-with-author/{id}` ==> Gets the book with author via `QueryDSL` eager fetching as per my suggestion above.

You can check the console logs to see the eager fetching works. When you call the third endpoint above you will see the following query generated:
`select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, bookauthor1_.id as id1_0_1_, book0_.name as name2_0_0_, book0_.publish_year as publish_3_0_0_, book0_.version as version4_0_0_, bookauthor1_.author as author5_0_1_ from book book0_ right outer join book bookauthor1_ on book0_.id=bookauthor1_.id where book0_.id=?`

On the other hand, the first endpoint will generate a query like `select book0_.id as id1_0_0_, book0_.name as name2_0_0_, book0_.publish_year as publish_3_0_0_, book0_.version as version4_0_0_ from book book0_ where book0_.id=?`

Comment: How do I insert with this model? If I try to `store` a Version with a VersionMappings, hibernate tries to insert two rows with different unique ids.